# Animate (this) nextAll parents with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to animate all of the parents of an element after the one clicked.

I have tried several iterations of the following:

```
$(this).parent().nextAll().animate({
  marginTop: '-=50px'
}, 500);
```

But I don't think I am getting the syntax right...

The parent element has a class of ".useritem" and I have a feeling I have to use it but I am not sure where as I thought specifying that the parent>of this item>all of them after>move up 50 px, would work.

Any help, guidance or advice would go a long way, thank you.

Edit 1: HTML

My HTML is created dynamically based on the server response. It will look like this however:

```
<div id='useritem' class='useritem'>
    <div id='msgnotification' class='msgnotification'>0</div>
    <img id='userimg' class='userimg' src='data/here'>
    <div id='usertxt' class='usertxt'>
        <div id='name' class='name'>User</div>
        <div id='username' class='username'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='useradd' class='useradd'><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i></div>
</div>
```

There are multiples of these stacked and when a user clicks on 'useradd' it's width is animated to 0 and the marginTop code should fire on every 'useritem' under it moving them up.

Comment: Have you tried `prevAll()` ?

Comment: Show your HTML and explain which elements you're trying to animate.

Comment: What do you mean by "all of the parents"? Do you mean the parent element of the next element, and then the parent of that parent, and the parent of that parent, etc.? I don't think an element can have multiple parents per se.

Comment: It looks like your code should work. Can you make a more complete example with multiple `.useritem` DIVs and CSS that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input and thank you to @Barmar for pointing out that my code /should/ have worked, I went over it again and realised where I was going wrong. I had wrapped the marginTop code in a timeout to wait for the initial clicked parent element to have a set animated width of 0. But of course when you try to call 'this' again, the element isn't there so the code didn't have an initial selector.

I fixed this by using .delay() instead. And now my initial code is working just without the timeout!

Thank you again for your input and time. This is the updated code:

```
$(this).parent().animate({
    'width': 0,
    'padding-left': 0,
    'padding-right': 0
}, 300, function() {
    $(this).next().animate({
        marginTop: '-=61px'
    }, 300);
});
```